# Sqlite: Insert new record by copying from old entry when inserting in the ID field

Tags: sqlite, triggers, insert

I want to create a duplicated entry when I insert a new record with an existing id number.
i.e. when I enter a new row with 2 in the ID field, it will automatically create a new entry by copying all the fields from the row with ID=2

I am using the below trigger but it is not working.
1) the trigger fails to work when inserting an existing number in the ID column 
2) when I changed new.ID to other field like new.col_2, the trigger works but an extra entry is also created after the trigger which I don't want it.

How can I solve these two issues or are there any workarounds for them?
Thanks.

```
CREATE TRIGGER "main"."NewTrigger" BEFORE INSERT ON "record" FOR EACH ROW WHEN new.ID is not NULL
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO record (col_1, col_2) 
    SELECT col_1, col_2 FROM record
    WHERE ID = new.ID;
END;
```

e.g. 
original table named "record"
ID | col_1 | col_2
1 | Ada | 20
2 | Ben | 56
3 | Candy | 82

when I insert a new entry like this:
ID | col_1 | col_2
2

the resulting table "record" will become:
ID | col_1 | col_2
1 | Ada | 20
2 | Ben | 56
3 | Candy | 82
4 | Ben | 56

Comment: Please show some example data, example statements, and the desired results.

Comment: an example is added

Answer (score 0):

The INSERT statements inserts a new row.
This is not what you want because you are already inserting a row.

What you need to do is to change the values in the row after it has been inserted:

```
CREATE TRIGGER NewTrigger
AFTER INSERT ON record
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN NEW.ID IS NOT NULL AND NEW.Col1 IS NULL
BEGIN
    UPDATE record
    SET (Col1, Col2) = (SELECT Col1, Col2
                        FROM record
                        WHERE ID = NEW.ID
                          AND Col1 IS NOT NULL);
    WHERE ID = NEW.ID
      AND Col1 IS NULL;
END;
```

(Using a row value requires SQLite 3.15.0 or later.)

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to mention that the ID column is the primary key, which is unique and auto incremented. The insert statement would not be carried out and I cannot use an after insert trigger

Comment: It is not possible to insert different values. You'd need an INSTEAD OF trigger on a view.

Comment: but a before insert trigger for the primary key is also not working when the value is duplicated in my trial. Do you know is it the case?

Comment: I want to do it on the table for simplicity purpose, do you know are there any workarounds for it?

Comment: There is no other workaround. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: sometimes I need to input nearly identical entry into the table, so I want to minimize the time for this task. When I do a search and find a similar old entry before inputting, I want to make a copy of the whole entry by just using the ID. Then I do not need to type it again. The actual table has about 20 columns.

Comment: Then just execute the `INSERT ... SELECT ...` statement.